# submit app to crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics

When I added a new configuration to my current iOS app and built, packaged it correctly, but it failed to deploy onto crashlytics:

> Deploying the app on Crashlytics... 2015-04-15 22:23:20.593 submit
>   Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.1 (11) 2015-04-15
>   22:23:26.167 submit Crashlytics: Unable to add release notes: Project
>   OMQA is inactive 2015-04-15 22:23:26.167 submit Crashlytics: Failed to
>   add notes to the release
>   A problem with crashlytics occured while deploying

Is that the problem of the package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alex here from Crashlytics. It looks like your app is still in a build state. Before submitting, run it locally first. Give that a try and you should be all set!

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, Alex, Actually, I am doing xcodebuild to package my app, and then deploy it to crashlytics, and all these things was done in a script. so how to make sure my app built finished. because only this app failed

Comment: Hi, Alex. the problem solved. Nothing wrong with the app or Crashlytics itself, only one thing, As I added a new configuration for the project, and named it to another APP name. like dev.omsignal.enterprise.OMQA, then I forgot to add dev.omsignal.enterprise.OMQA from Crashlytics plugin.

Comment: @YuQIAN I'm glad to hear you got it sorted out!

Comment: We have actually same problem, however the application can be submitted with the XCode Fabric plugin only:

```2015-12-10 12:41:00.096 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (15)

2015-12-10 12:41:08.119 submit Crashlytics: Unable to add release notes: Project XXXXXX is inactive

2015-12-10 12:41:08.119 submit Crashlytics: Failed to add notes to the release```

Comment: @igraczech sounds like you haven't fully onboarded the app yet. Can you let me know the package name so I can check it out?

Comment: Solved with your tech-support. I cannot post package names of the next big com.ibm.thebeastapps to the wild, however issue was that your old version of API didn't respond meaningfully to incorrect submission request (e.g. when using API key for different app/team there errors were not descriptive enough).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, now solved: Incorrectly merged project did contain our developer's private Fabric/Crashlytics API Key/Secret instead of our Enterprise one.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue by using correct API key and secret (organizational instead of developers') and discussed this with Mr. Bonnell on Support. The API error should become more explanatory soon. Sorry for not sharing the package name here, it's confidential.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem just:

1. Going to https://fabric.io
2. Click in Settings
3. Click Apps
4. Select you app
5. Versions

Check if the version that you're trying to distribute is active! You can check in Hidden Versions and just toggle the version to `Version Enabled`!