# fabric build failed while sending build to testers

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, google-fabric

[image]

Not sure what to do with this error ? Any advice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29664478/5461400

Comment: Thanks harshal ..for pointing me out in correct direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [submit app to crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664478/submit-app-to-crashlytics)